# .htaccess rewrite to subfolder with codeigniter rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2

I have a site that needs to exist in a subfolder

```
example.com/site
```

But i'm trying to use the .htaccess to remove any links that contain www (to make sure codeigniter csrf doesn't throw errors), so i've added

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/site/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works well when there is a page identifier specified, so

```
www.example.com/site/book rewrites to example.com/site/book
```

But when there is no page identifier specified I get a 404

```
www.example.com/site rewrites to example.com/site//usr/local/pem/vhosts/103480/webspace/httpdocs/new
```

I was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction?

This is my full .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/site/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Do you have an additional htaccess file in the `site` subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess in question is in the `site` subdirectory, sorry i should have been clearer. The updated answer from faa has solved my problem though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.    [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  http://example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you've suggested doesn't include the redirection to the subfolder, and when i add it back in `RewriteRule ^(.*)  http://example.com/site/$1 [R=301,L]` it rewrites to the same url as mentioned in the question when trying to access `www.example.com/site`

Comment: The code in my answer removes `www` from the request. That's all. Now, do you want to redirect everything to directory `/site`? If so, you have to make sure first the request is not to `/site`. I can update my answer if you explain more in detail what you want.

Comment: I want to redirect the request as: www.example.com/site => example.com/site and www.example.com/site/book => example.com/site/book

What i have works for the second case but not for the first

Comment: Well, that's exactly what the code in my answer does. Just removes the `www` and keeps the URI-path as requested. You don't have to add anything. Replace the top 2 lines in your question with those in my answer.

Comment: When i add in your two lines `www.example.com/site/book` redirects to `example.com/book`, it removes the subfolder

Comment: There is something missing. The behavior you describe makes no sense, the whole URI-path is being passed to the substitution URL in the rule in my answer. If you are not adding your original rule and there is no more code, something doesn't fit. Is `site` by any chance a sub-domain?

Comment: Yeah, the whole codeigniter structure is installed on `site`, `example.com` is a different site. And the .htaccess is within `site`. Thank you for your help, i appreciate your time, maybe i'll try come at the problem from a different angle

Comment: Modified my answer. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you're just missing a [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

Depending on where the `.htaccess` file is, try either

```
RewriteBase /
```

or

```
RewriteBase /site
```

*Never* test with `301` enabled, see this answer
[Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)
for details.

Comment: Thanks for the link olaf, that will be good reading for me to try and improve in this area